# Use momentjs in angular to format time

Tags: angularjs, time, momentjs

I'm having trouble getting Moment in Angular to format my time like I would like. I have the date filter working here:

```
<h4>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
```

But when I try to use this format to print out a time, my time disappears completely out of the browser. This is what I am typing:

```
<div class="row">
           {{event.time | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}
         </div>
```

I am using Firebase if that matters. Also, the input to get the time is the HTML5 input type=time attribute.

Comment: `event.time` doesn't represent a valid "date" value for moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `type=time` for an input, the value is stored as a string which only represents a time, such as "1:00" or "13:00".  The amDateFormat filter needs a value that can be interpreted as a date which can be a Date object, a number value for a timestamp, or a properly formatted string date. The time values that you will get using `type=time` are not valid date strings so `amDateFormat` can't properly parse the value.

The easiest way to make it work is to just concatenate the value of `event.date` and `event.time` before you use the `amDateFormat` filter:

```
<div class="row">
  {{event.date + ' ' + event.time | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}
</div>
```

A better solution is to use a function where you pass in the date and time, or just the time and construct something that *can* be interpreted as a date, or is a date object.

```
<div class="row">
  {{ combine(event.date,event.time) | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}
</div>
```

simple combine function

```
  $scope.combine = function(date,time) {
    if (date && time) {
      return date + ' ' + time;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };
```

I still think it's kinda hacky to have to add a date to the time like that but it works and you may even end up joining them together anyway in your data model.  The best solution I believe would be to just have one event.dateAndTime object that you can use to represent *both* the date and time -- and you can do this using the `type=datetime-local` html5 type (at least in Chrome it worked for me).

```
<dir>Date and time: <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="event.datetime"></dir>
<h4>{{event.datetime | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</h4>
<div class="row">
  event.datetime time: {{ event.datetime | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}
</div>
```

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OERKK9ilxFwUlKLKirtl?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much -- I used your second solution (making a function) and it worked great. You rule.

Comment: Why can't we do this type of formatting using the default date filter in angularJs.

Comment: You can do that type of (time) formatting with the default date filter, see the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OERKK9ilxFwUlKLKirtl?p=preview