# How can I use angular-moment to set the format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I have a date, that look like this(from json):

```
detailAssets.CONTRACT_END_DATE = '201811';
```

and I am using angular-moment to format to date, but results are not correct

```
<tr ng-repeat="assetsdetail in detailAssets | filter:profileId">

        <td>{{assetsdetail.CONTRACT_END_DATE | amDateFormat : 'YYYY-MM'}}</td> // shows 1970-01
 </tr>
```

how can I set the format using angular-moment, like this`? :

```
moment(detailAssets.CONTRACT_END_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
```

because the above method worked in console and showed the right results : 2018-11

Answer (score 0):

Is detailAssets an array or object?

If it's an object, you should not use ng-repeat on an object.

Comment: I am getting data from json file, which is can array of objects

Comment: according to [this post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132961/use-momentjs-in-angular-to-format-time), you may want to pass a date object instead of a string so amDateFormat can properly parse the value